# Create a treeview from a List<customClass> WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I would like to create an `TreeView` from an `List<PhonesFromStudents>`.

My custom class is `PhonesFromStudents`

```
public class PhonesFromStudents
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Phones { get; set; } 
}
```

XAML is :

```
 <TreeView  x:Name="tv_source" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ListStudents}" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

MainWindows.cs

```
 internal MainWindow(List<PhonesFromStudents> list)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.ListStudents = list;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Example :
2 students
Thomas - iPhone8,iPhone6
Lucas - iPhone4s, S8

i would like to have

```
Thomas
|_____iPhone8
|_____iPhone6

Lucas
|_____iPhone4s
|_____S8
```

But I get an empty list from UI.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tv_source" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ListStudents}" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PhonesFromStudents}" ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

...and make sure that `ListStudents` is a public property:

```
public List<PhonesFromStudents> ListStudents { get; set; }
```